# Spinnaker authenticate K8s with service account. Not with system:anonymous

Tags: kubernetes, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I see spinnaker using `system:anonymous` user to authenticate K8s. But I want a specific user(which I created already in K8s) to authenticate K8s. I used below `kubeconfig` to use user `veeru`

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: RETRACTED
    server: https://xx.xx.xx.220:8443
  name: xx-xx-xx-220:8443
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: xx-xx-xx-220:8443
    namespace: default
    user: veeru/xx-xx-xx-220:8443
  name: area-51/xx-xx-xx-220:8443/veeru
current-context: area-51/xx-xx-xx-220:8443/veeru
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: veeru/xx-xx-xx-220:8443
  user:
    client-certificate-data: RETRACTED
    client-key-data: RETRACTED
```

And I specified(like [here](https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/wiki/Kubernetes-Implementation)) `user` in config(~/.hal/config) like below

```
kubernetes:
      enabled: true
      accounts:
      - name: my-k8s-account
        requiredGroupMembership: []
        providerVersion: V1
        dockerRegistries:
        - accountName: my-docker-registry2
          namespaces: []
        configureImagePullSecrets: true
        namespaces: ["area-51"]
        user: veeru
        omitNamespaces: []
        kubeconfigFile: /home/ubuntu/.kube/config
        oauthScopes: []
        oAuthScopes: []
      primaryAccount: my-k8s-account
```

But still spinnaker is using `system:anonymous`

```
2018-01-22 08:35:13.929 ERROR 4639 --- [pool-4-thread-1] c.n.s.c.o.DefaultOrchestrationProcessor  : com.netflix.spinnaker.clouddriver.kubernetes.v1.deploy.exception.KubernetesOperationException: Get Service openshifttest-dev in area-51 for account my-k8s-account failed: User "system:anonymous" cannot get services in the namespace "area-51": User "system:anonymous" cannot get services in project "area-51"
```

Is there any way to specify user that spinnaker should use configured user other than `system:anonymous`

## **UPDATE-1**

Followed: https://blog.spinnaker.io/spinnaker-kubernetes-rbac-c40f1f73c172

Got the `secret` from `kubectl describe secret spinnaker-service-account-token-9sl6q` and update in `kubeconfig` like below

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: REDACTED
    server: https://xx.xx.xx.xx:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    namespace: webapp
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: spinnaker-service-account
  name: spinnaker-context
current-context: spinnaker-context
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
- name: spinnaker-service-account
  user:
    token: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9....
```

Than I ran `sudo hal deploy`

```
....
! ERROR Unable to communicate with your Kubernetes cluster: Failure
  executing: GET at: https://xx.xx.xx.xx:6443/api/v1/namespaces. Message:
  Forbidden! User spinnaker-service-account doesn't have permission. namespaces is
  forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:spinnaker-service-account" cannot
  list namespaces at the cluster scope..
? Unable to authenticate with your Kubernetes cluster. Try using
  kubectl to verify your credentials.
....
```

I'm able run

```
$ kubectl get namespace webapp
NAME      STATUS    AGE
webapp    Active    22m
```

I have specified `webapp` namespace and user as `spinnaker-service-account` in `~/.hal/config`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/) with basic authentication disabled. I have my spinnaker use a dedicated K8s service account that I created. In my `~/.kube/config` I have tokens for each K8s cluster.

```
users:
- name: gke_operation-covfefe-1_asia-east1_testing-asia-east1
  user:
    token: token1
- name: gke_operation-covfefe-1_europe-west1_testing-europe-west1
  user:
    token: token2
- name: gke_operation-covfefe-1_us-central1_testing-us-central1
  user:
    token: token3
```

I got these tokens by running

```
kubectl get secret spinnaker-service-account -o json \
 | jq -r .data.token \
 | base64 -d
```

and then manually updating my `~/.kube/config` file.

Make sure your service account has the required RBAC permissions. See [blog post here](https://blog.spinnaker.io/spinnaker-kubernetes-rbac-c40f1f73c172).

#### Update:

Also make sure you give the service account the required RBAC permissions. See the "Role" section of the blog post above or the [guide here](https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/providers/kubernetes-v2/#kubernetes-role-rbac). When you test the RBAC permissions with `kubectl` make sure you're using the same service account as the one Spinnaker is using.

#### Update 2

If you want spinnaker to act on all namespaces, use ClusterRole and ClusterRoleBinding in your RBAC. The blog post only uses Role and RoleBinding which restricts actions to a particular namespace(s). See [this guide](https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/providers/kubernetes-v2/#kubernetes-role-rbac) for the Cluster* way. Note the [PR to fix a typo here](https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker.github.io/pull/520).

Comment: Hey David Xia, thanks for the answer. I was unable to pull the `secret` for `spinnaker-service-account`, getting `Error from server (NotFound): secrets "spinnaker-service-account" not found`. I can see servic account with `kubectl get sa`. I have tested in GKE. Any thoughts?

Comment: ok I got `token`/`secret` and specified in kubeconfig file. But spinnaker is trying to fetch details at cluster scope. Can you check `UPDATE-1` in my question

Comment: Yes I did, I used same yml files from blog you said to create service account.